# What to set as web-uri for exploded WAR in Java EE application created by Intellij IDEA 12?

Tags: jakarta-ee, intellij-idea, application.xml

If I create a new Java EE application in Intellij IDEA 12:

[image: New JavaEE Web Module]

Using Web Application 2.5, JSF 2.0, Application Server Glassfish 3.1.2.2, and Java EE 6:

[image: Technology stack selections]

`application.xml` is autogenerated with this text as its content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<application xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/application_6.xsd"
             version="6">

</application>
```

This application will not successfully deploy because the `<module>` tag is missing from `application.xml`:

```
The content of element 'application' is not complete. One of
'{"http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee":application-name,
"http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee":description,
"http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee":display-name,
"http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee":icon,
"http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee":initialize-in-order,
"http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee":module}' is expected.
```

Should the `module` tag have been added automatically by the IDE?  If so, why hasn't it been?  If not, what should I set the `web-uri` tag (`<module><web><web-uri>`) to if I want to use the default `web:war exploded` artifact?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a bug. If you choose 'Java Module' instead of 'JavaEE Web Module' on the first step and then select 'Web Application', 'JavaEE Application' and 'Application Server' on the second step the application.xml file should be generated properly.

Comment: Bug progress [can be tracked here](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-98185).